# How do I set the HTML element of a text field?

Tags: 7, panels

My request couldn't be simpler - I have a custom text field on a node (field type `text`), and I want this field to be placed in a Panels layout in a `<h3>` element.

For `Node title`, I can choose the HTML element. For text fields, there seems to be no such option. The available formatters are `Default`, `Trimmed` and `Plain text`, none of which have any settings. Views fields have all sorts of easy field rewriting features, but I can't find anything equivalent in Panels.

How can I get the drop down of HTML elements like you get for Node Title for a custom field? Or change the output another way?

I'd prefer not to have to rewrite my entire Panels layout and create a whole new region for this one field in its .tpl file simply to put some text in a `<h3>`.

Comment: Any feedback on your search progress ? Did Panels extra styles fit your need ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Panels Extra Styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_extra_styles) ? As per module page :

> **Panels Wrapper**
>
> Wrap your panes and regions with unlimited possibilities.
>   Go HTML5! Wrap your content in the newly defined tags. Add custom
>   containers and HTM
>
> **Wrapper: Element**
>
> Wrap any region or pane with one of several dozen tags, including
>   HTML5 elements.
>
> **Wrapper: Raw**
>
> Wrap any region or pane with a custom raw prefix and suffix.
>
> Sample output after applying the wrapper elements on 1 region and 2
>   content panes: the powered by block and a main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Because Drupal, this requires another custom module, [Clean Markup](https://drupal.org/project/clean_markup):

- Download clean_markup and enable the `clean_markup_panels` submodule
- Edit your panel pane's **Style** settings from its cog menu
- Choose the Clean Markup option
- This allows you to choose the HTML wrapper for the pane from a huge list that includes HTML5 elements as well as every H* element

<strike>BONUS - you can also turn off the unnecessary wrappers Panels loves to add to panes.</strike> Actually, no, despite the name it seems to stuff the `<h3>` full of divs regardless of your settings, I don't understand why. If you don't mind your element being full of unnecessary divs, this is a good option.